# Subtracting a set with a set of subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have set $A = \{a,b,c\}$ and $B = \{b,\{c\}\}$ then what is $A - B$ ?

I am confused about how to subtract if I have a subset in one of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $A-B = \{ x \in A | x \notin B \}$ so as the only element of $A$ that is also in $B$ is  $b$, then $A-B = \{a,c \}$

Answer (score 3):

Don't fall for the "what about elements that are sets, what do we do with the elements of the those" trap.

Elements are elements.  If those elements are sets whats *in* those sets have nothing to do with the set you are dealing with.

$A \setminus B$ is that you take all the elements of $A$ that are not elements of $B$. Period.

The elements of $A$ are $a,b, c$.  The elements of $B$ are $b$ and $\{c\}$.

So we go through the elements of $A$ one by one:  $a$.  Is $a$ in $B$?  Well, $a$ is not $b$.  And $a$ is not $\{c\}$.  So no $a$ is not in  $B$.  So $a$ is in $A \setminus B$.

$b$.  Is $b$ in $B$?  Well, $b$ is $b$ so yes, $b$ is in $B$.  So $b$ is not in $A \setminus B$.

And $c$.  Is $c$ in $B$? Well, $c$ is not $b$.  And $c$ is not $\{c\}$.  ("But $c$ is *in* $\{c\}$!", I hear someone shout.  To which I respond very grouchily and surly "I *said* don't fall for that trap!"  So what if $c$ is *in* $\{c\}$?  We don't care if $c$ is in $\{c\}$.  What matters is whether $c$ *is* $\{c\}$ and it isn't!  $c$ is $c$ and $\{c\}$ is a set containing $c$.  Those are two utterly different things.)  So $c$ is not an element of $B$ but it is an element of $A$.  So $c$ is in $A\setminus B$.

So $A \setminus B = \{a,c\}$

Answer (score 0):

Just by the definition we have $$A\setminus B=\{a,c\}$$

Comment: So A - B = {a} ?

Comment: @Vyas Ramankulangara No! It's $\{a,c\}.$ Read the definition of the set-minus.

Comment: $A-B$ and $A \setminus B$ are different notations for the same thing.